# CoreBLuetooth limitation ios cannot scan all bluetooth devices?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

?

When it comes to the implementation about scanning BLuetooth device, I have found that only BLE devices can be scanned by iOS running iOS7.1.1 but all Bluetooth devices can be scanned by Android devices. Does it imply that the framework CoreBluetooth can only scan BLE devices ? What other frameworks can be used to scan all bluetooth devices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS devices don't scan all bluetooth devices. It has list of profiles that only detected by iOS devices.
[From Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647)

Comment: It seems that SPP communication is impossible for iOS devices and bluetooth sensor (2.1 - 3.0 )  is impossible unless using CoreBluetooth which creates a virtual SPP for communication but bluetooth sensor 4.0 is given.

Comment: Communication with devices other than BLE requires MFI (Made For iPhone) licensing and support. I disagree with this requirement, but they seldom (read: never) ask me before making these decisions. https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/